# pandas combine two values

Tags: python, pandas

i have the below dataframe and i want to check the column ID if it has more than one board then the new board value should be the " 1st value / 2nd value " like below :

original Dataframe:

| ID | Board |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxA | Card80 |
| xxxxB | Card80 |
| xxxxC | Card80 |
| yyyyA | Card01 |
| yyyyA | Card02 |
| yyyyB | Card01 |
| yyyyB | Card02 |
| yyyyC | Card01 |
| yyyyC | Card02 |

Result:

| ID | Board |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxA | Card80 |
| xxxxB | Card80 |
| xxxxC | Card80 |
| yyyyA | Card01/Card02 |
| yyyyB | Card01/Card02 |
| yyyyC | Card01/Card02 |

i hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `ID`, then pass the aggregate as `'/'.join` for  `Board` column

```py
>>> df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'Board':'/'.join})

      ID          Board
0  xxxxA         Card80
1  xxxxB         Card80
2  xxxxC         Card80
3  yyyyA  Card01/Card02
4  yyyyB  Card01/Card02
5  yyyyC  Card01/Card02
```